# Convert MySQL DateTime to GMT without CONVERT_TZ

Tags: mysql, gmt

I have a MySQL table which has a date stored as a DateTime. I am trying to build a MySQL query that displays the date in GMT format (example: 20140310T050000Z).

The mysql server that I am using does not have the mysql.time_zone_name table populated with values. The server admins are unwilling to run the mysql_tzinfo_to_sql command to populate the table, so I cannot use the CONVERT_TZ function in my sql query.

Using date_format(myDate, '%Y%m%dT'), I am able to get most of the date in GMT, but I'm a bit confused about how to get the ending part. The ending is sometimes '050000Z' and sometimes '060000Z' (depending on whether or not the time is in daylight savings time or not.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to get the '05' or '06' ending part of the time without using CONVERT_TZ?

Thanks.

Comment: would the 'gm' versions of the 'date' / 'time' be useful i.e. gmdate()?

Comment: @RyanVincent - I unfortunately don't have php available, it is a pure sql query displayed to the user.

Comment: my bad, did not read the instructions properly! ;-/